# How can make theme for android

Tags: android, android-theme

I want to know whats the formal and systematic way to make an android theme.
I have some knowledge about android programming and I can develop an android app;
I want the best way to create android theme, What is it ?
Thanks ,

Comment: look into this [Link 1](http://javatechig.com/android/android-styles-and-themes-tutorial) , [Link 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_theme_demo_example.htm)

Comment: thanks but I want create them for menu , icons, .... (Like Go themes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at http://www.androidnova.org/theming-tutorial-for-android-part-1-basics-and-xmls/

and http://gotheme.goforandroid.com/golauncherthemefactory/ for Go Themes

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following links...

[Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

[Themes](https://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html)

BTW, you could have just gone to the official [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/index.html) website and search for this stuff yourself...or even just used Google.

Comment: thanks but I want create them for menu , icons, .... (Like Go themes)